# Taking new iOS version into account when submitting an update to the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, compatibility, ios7

We are just about to submit an update to the App Store for some minor bug fixes and enhancements. The curve ball at this point is iOS 7.

My question is, what do I have worry about in regards to iOS 7? I'm not phased in utilizing any of the new features of iOS 7, we just want to make sure it works with it fine.

Just wondering if anyone could give advice on what I should be taking into account for this update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a pretty complex question. I recommend the following strategy:

1) Submit your app update as it is for iOS 6, or whatever versions you are currently supporting.

2) Begin building and testing your app against the iOS 7 Beta using XCode 5 and get a feel for the major things that you are going to have to fix for iOS 7.

3) Read up on some of the big changes in iOS 7, in particular you should be familiar with the iOS 7 transition guide, available here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/Scoping.html

4) Watch the following developer videos to get a good overview of the new changes:

[Platforms State of the Union](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/)
[Building Interfaces for iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the following documents:

- [iOS 7 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013202)
- [iOS 7 APIs Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013203)
- [What's new in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008246)

The most obvious changes are to the UI, so unless you're making a game, I'd perhaps also spend time reading [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to submit the app using Xcode 4.6.2.  Past betas of Xcode have not allowed you to submit versions to the app store.

If Xcode 4.6.2 doesn't give you any error messages, you should be able to submit your app without a problem.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't worry about iOS 7 now, as it's a beta. However, I recommend start adopting your app to iOS 7 on a branch or something like that. This way, when iOS 7 is finally released, your app will be ready.

Comment: Hi Marcelo. Thanks for your response. Does it warrant downloading the beta and testing the app on it just to see if it still runs?